# Learning Project: Use Powershell to organize folders in a NAS

Tags: powershell

I am exploring PowerShell and would like to try and use it to organize my music folder. I have zero experience doing so, but thought it would be a great little project to explore PowerShell. I do have a background in Data Science and am familiar with programming in R and basic C++ so I believe to have at least basic skills.

At home I have a Western Digital MyCloudEX2Ultra with 12tb in Raid 1 (I think) NAS where the files are stored.

Firstly, I tried to see if I could find my NAS with PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\luisf> net view
Server Name            Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\LAPTOP-FQSN7626
\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA      2-Bay NAS
The command completed successfully.

PS C:\Users\luisf>
```

I could not access files in the NAS drive though as I thought:

```
PS C:\> cd \\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA
```

Output:

```
cd : Cannot find path '\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd \\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS C:\>
```

So at this point I don't have any clue on how to access this since it doesn't work as a simple change directory.

So I decided to manually copy the original olders to another folder not to lose any of the original files and folders.

As I copied the folders I got the following message:
[Name is too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAeWa.png)

Which made me even more worried that I definitely need a "PowerShell" solution to this. My goal would be to copy all files and sub-directories from `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music`
The folders which contain songs are:

`\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\2019` -

`\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music` - 5093 folders

`\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\iTunes 2\iTunes Music` - 12175 folders

A problem that I foresee coming is how to handle sub-directories having the same names as such:
`\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\iTunes 2\iTunes Music\16 Bit Lolitas`

`\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\16 Bit Lolitas`

And even sub-directories:

`\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\16 Bit Lolitas\Murder Weapon`

What I would like guidance with on how to do this to learn PowerShell:

Duplicate the main song directory not to damage or lose files:
Duplicate `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music` and rename it to `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music_Organized`

`\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music_Organized` should be an exact replica of `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music`, which have the two old itunes directories I want to consolidate.

Move all folders and files from: `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music_Organized\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music` - 5093

To: `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\iTunes 2\iTunes Music` - 12175 folders

While merging sub folders with same names. Merge `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music_Organized\2019` into `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Music\iTunes 2\iTunes Music`

That way I would have a copy of the original files, consolidated under one folder where folders were merged as max as possible while not losing any folders due to long name or other issues.

Is this too much of a project to tackle? Any kind of feedback or direction would largely be appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Best regards,

LF.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, DNS resolution on home networks for NAS is patchy at best. If you have no access to the DNS server on your router then the best option is to add your NAS in as a hosts file entry - find the IP address of your NAS and specify to your computer where it s:

https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_use_the_hosts_file/

Secondly, you cannot connect ("CD") to a network path like that. Map a drive on your computer to the NAS and then CD to the drive letter - you should then be able to query files on the NAS using that drive letter

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  @Scepticalist
Interesting that you mentioned because I do have connectivity issues with the NAS in Win10.
I looked at my router config (Netgear Nighthawk R7000) in Advanced > Setup > Internet Setup two check boxes: 
Get Automatically from ISP (currently checked)
Use these DNS servers: 
- Primary DNS (input box for ip)
- Secondary DNS (input box for ip)

I also see the device's IP on another screen 192.168.1.10 is this what I put there as secondary and a google dns as primary?

Comment: No, unless you know what you;re doing don;t mess with DNS settings on your router - let the ISP deal with it.
If you;re using DHCP, the devices should get and register themselves in DNS settings automatically. Problem being that some NAS/Unix devices don't handle this well.